# How do you use an if/else statement in python (pls dont close)

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

I have a project where i have to translate binary to hex. and decimal

Here is the code, it might not be that pretty any help is greatly appreciated:
the thing is that when i put in a 1 or a 0 it still gives me: There is an error please re-type your binary number. (one's and zero's) from my code

```
binary = raw_input("What Binary up to 8-bits would you like to use?")

if len(binary) <= 8:

    for b in range(1,len(binary)+1):

        if b ==2 or b==3 or b==4 or b==5 or b==6 or b==7 or b==8 or b==9:

          print "**There is an error please re-type your binary number. (one's and zero's)**"
        else:
            print "Your code is too long! it needs to be 8 or less characters to 
proccess!"
```

Comment: python already has this as a builtin - you can cast strings to integers, using whatever base you want. E.g., int(user_input, 2) for binary. Take a look here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int

Comment: @MooingRawr no, the OP doesn't compare `binary` to anything.

Comment: That long `if` statement can be more simply written as `if 2 <= b <= 9:`

Answer (score 2):

```
for b in range(1, len(binary)+1):
```

You're not iterating over the characters in the binary string, you're iterating from 1 to the length of the string. Also, I think your `else` block is overindented. Use this instead:

```
for b in binary:
```

This isn't going to fix all of your problems, though. For one, `b` will be a one-character string, so `b==2` will always be false. I'd suggest changing `b` to an int and then seeing if it is greater than 1 - `int(b) > 1`.

However, what you *really* should be doing is testing each step you're not completely sure about to make sure you're actually getting what you expect. If you inserted a `print(b)` (or `print b` for Python 2) line in the `for` loop, you would have seen that it was not the values you expected.